# clear timeout on select change()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get and show data from database every 5 seconds using AJAX and I use recursive `setTimeout` for this purpose, something like code below

```
var timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
  alert( "tick" );
  timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Also there are 3 filters (`select` elements) on my page  `#books-filter, #authors-filter, #stores-filter` and every time I choose some option in select list or change my choice, I need to clear timeout and set it again with new 5 seconds, and after 5 second get new data.

My code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {


"use strict"

  var $body = $('body');

  function filterBooks() {
    var start = null,
      interval = 2000;

function select() {
  $("#books-filter, #authors-filter, #stores-filter").change(function() {
    clearTimeout(start);
    timer();
  });
}

select();

function timer() {
  start = setTimeout(function tick() {
    start = setTimeout(tick, interval);
    filter();
  }, interval);
}

timer();

function filter() {
  var $form = $('#filter');

  var url = $form.attr('action');
  var data = $form.serialize();

  if(data !== '') {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',       
    error: function(response){
    },
    success: function(response) {
      //console.log(response);
        }
      }); 
    }
  }

}

  filterBooks();

});
```

but I'm not sure, will `clearTimeout` work this way?

Comment: why not just use setInterval and then on select change event clear and init it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, if you want some function to be executed multiple times with some time interval, you will benefit more from `setInterval()` approach:

```
function retrieveMyData() {
    // your ajax stuff
}

var myInterval = setInterval(retrieveMyData, 5000);
```

Then, when change event fires on your `select` element, you just restart your interval

```
$(document).on('change', '#your-target-select', function () {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = setInterval(retrieveMyData, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As markoffden said, you may consider using the intervals instead since it is the direct function for implementing periodic loops. 
But to answer your question: 
`clearTimeout` will work in listeners as long as you can retrieve the corresponding timeout's ID. 
Here is an example storing the current timeout globally, with a flag and buttons to switch between timeout loops: 
http://codepen.io/clemeno/pen/aNmzdm